# Learn Zend Framework version

Tags: zend-framework, zend-framework2

I would like to learn Zend framework and I am at a loss when it comes to versions.
It is possible to learn directly Zend framework 2 without consulting the documentation of Zend framework 1?

Answer (score 0):

Since both version aren't compatible together, there is no point in learning ZF 1.x (unless you have to maintain a ZF 1.x project).

As with many frameworks/libraries, errors have been made in term of design and mecanics which are often corrected in newer releases.

So unless you will have to maintaint an older application, go for the most recent (as long as what you want to do is supported)

Zend Framework 2 > Zend Framework 1 (theorically, I haven't worked with ZF2)

This is not a definitive rule to live by. Python is a good example, many useful Python 2.x haven't yet been ported to Python 3.x. It illustrate that you can't always pick the higher version blindly. You have to search for functionnalities based on your needs.

Comment: The two versions of ZF are so different they really appeal to different audiences.

Comment: They are too different to be compatible with one another, but if you have no knowledge at all about the inner workings of ZF and you don't have legacy applications to maintain, there is not point in learning ZF1 since no new development will be made and the code base will not evolve anymore. There might be minor revision for bug fixing, but don't expect new features

Comment: I would never point a newer php developer to ZF2. I'd be to afraid of them getting discouraged. The complexity and abstraction have been cranked way up making it much more difficult to grok if you lack a more formal CS education. ZF1 on the other hand is fairly easy to grok for most newer or self taught developers. Also there is currently a lack of resources (tutorial, blog, book...) for new develpoers to ZF2. Where as ZF1 has many resources to assist a newer developers education.

Comment: If you learn a framework for programming learning, you are doing something wrong, you should reinvent the wheel and build your own mvc framework with at least form management and db transactions, but if you want to make an application to go in production an you are already proficient in the language of your framework of choice (here, PHP), there is no point to learn an older one for the sake of simplicity, since It's on the way down in popularity and maintenance